# Different ways of setting an index of an array used by a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

Question,

Does anyone have a tidier solution compared to what I have done below?

Setup,

I need to download load data from a backend and put it into a `tableView` in a specific order that is determined from the backend.

Problem,

I get the list order from the backend but the order is messed up cause I was appending to an `array`. When I tried to add to a specific `index` I would get `index out of range` (of course) cause if the first item downloaded was supposed at `index` 6 then it would be out of range.

My solution,

Here is my solution that works but I am interested in seeing how someone could improve on this or sees another way to accomplish the same thing,

```
 if self.array.count >= indexNumberFromBackend {
        self.array.insert(data, at: indexNumberFromBackend)
    } else {
        if indexNumber > self.array.count {
            if self.array.count <= indexNumberFromBackend {
               self.array.append(data)
            } else {
               self.array.insert(data, at: indexNumberFromBackend)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just sort the array?

Comment: Yeah, I could just do that haha. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider putting data in a dictionary and then generate a sorted array. Alternatively, you could store the backend index along with the data to sort the array later.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Andy and Conrad my code became this,

```
self.myArray.append(data)
self.myArray.sort(by: { $0.cellOrder > $1.cellOrder })
```